# PostgreSQL filter by timestamp

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timestamp

I have a table named `report` that looks like following;

[image]

which are the types of,

[image]

Here I'm trying to change the rows filtering by `order_id` and `start_picking_hour`. There is no problem with `order_id`. However, I cannot achieve anything when I filter by `start_picking_hour`.

For example, the following code works, and SQL Manager says that "2 rows affected";

```
UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366
```

However, I'm trying to filter by both `order_id` and `start_picking_hour`. I am not sure about how to filter by a type of `timestamp`. None of the following queries I tried worked. Each one returned a message of "0 rows affected".

```
UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM','dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss')

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51','dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss')

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM','dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss')

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51','dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss')

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = '2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM'

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = 2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = '2/17/2015 10:12:51'

UPDATE report SET picked_count = 10 WHERE order_id = 168366 and
      start_picking_hour = 2/17/2015 10:12:51
```

What is the exact way of filtering by `timestamp` in a `WHERE` clause? I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: What do you get with this query: SELECT * FROM report WHERE start_picking_hour = TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM','dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss');

Comment: I got an empty result

Comment: A `timestamp` also contains fractional seconds (which your timestamp literal does not have). Not sure if your SQL client displays them, but you could try: `date_trunc('second', start_picking_hour) = timestamp '2015-02-17 10:12:51'` that will get rid of milliseconds in the `start_picking_hour` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This one worked! Thanks very much. Write answer if you wish so that it could be read better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `timestamp` also contains fractional seconds (milliseconds). A timestamp literal like the one you are using (`TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM','dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss')`) does not contain milliseconds.

You can use the `date_trunc()` function to "remove" the milliseconds from the timestamp values (they are not "removed" - just set to zero):

```
where date_trunc('second', start_picking_hour) = timestamp '2015-02-17 10:12:51'
```

<sup>(I prefer the ANSI timestamp literals over `to_timestamp()` because they are shorter to write, portable and unambiguous)</sup>

Note that this will prevent the usage of an index on the start_picking_hour column.

If you don't care about the milliseconds, you can define your column as `timestamp(0)` instead. In that case milliseconds will never be stored and you can compare the column directly to a timestamp literal (that does not contain milliseconds). In that case an index on that column *can* be used.

Comment: You could also use BETWEEN: start_picking_hour BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:51 AM','dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2/17/2015 10:12:52 AM','dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss')